# Upgrade to 12.5.1 made my user account break

Tags: macos, monterey

I am on a 2013 Mac Pro with my user folder on an external drive, "Bigger", while the original internal with apps and such is "Fast".

The update to 12.5.1 caused my external drive to be renamed "Bigger 1". It also created a new drive, "Bigger", which appears to be physically located on Fast. It created a new User folder for me on this new drive, so I don't have access to any of my files.

Has anyone seen this before and have any advice on how to unwind this?

Comment: Did you update from 12.5? Also, can you run `diskutil list` and add the result to the question as text?

Comment: This happened because the external hard drive was not available at some point in the process and so it re-created a folder at /Volumes/Bigger/...etc for your user account. When you reconnected Bigger it added `1` to the end to not conflict with the since-created folder `/Volumes/Bigger`

Comment: @Ezekiel - so is this simply a folder in the Volumes dir? Can I simply delete it and rename the original one back?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I believe so, yes. If you delete it then boot it'll mount properly (no need to rename) and appear in the right place. Can't say I've ever had my user folder caught up in a mess like this though so ...best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the solution is as follows:

1. log on as admin, or any admin-capable account NOT on the drive in question
2. in terminal, `mv` the new folder to something else, `Bigger` to `Biggernew` in my case
3. `mv` the renamed `Bigger 1` back to `Bigger`
4. in System Preferences->Accounts, change the path to the user directory to `Bigger` (because I changed it to `Bigger 1` to get logged in, not everyone will have done this)
5. after testing, delete `Biggernew`, it's simply a folder you can drag to the trash

Comment: In recent versions of macOS, you may need to grant Terminal full access to the disk, which is controlled even for the admin account. It's in Security settings.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, if you have your user folder in a non-standard location *(i.e. on a different volume from the system volume)*, then if the OS can't find that volume, it will create a new (empty) user account, either in the default location, `/Users`, or (which seems to have happened here) with the same path, under `/Volumes`.

Comment: Sure, but the question remains why it can't find the volume. I suspect it mounts externals late in the boot process and if it simply waited a second it would work fine.